# Enable artisan command LARAVEL

Tags: php, git, bash, laravel

Im trying to create a `table` through `migration` but I can't create because it gives me an error like this `bash: php: command not found`. I searched through the net but still cant find the solutions. I found some useful information that when `'*'` are next to the command, the command is disabled. How can i enable it? Can someone help me about this?

Here's the picture

[image]

Comment: can you check if there is php installed in your machine?

Comment: If you can't run `php` from your interactive shell, it's possible that your `$PATH` is incorrect, or that the `php` CLI tools are not installed. This isn't so much a programming problem as it is a programming *environment* problem. Edit your question and include your operating system. Use your package manager (apt? yum? pkg? portage? pkgsrc?) to search for packages with `php` in the name and let us know what you find. Has this ever worked before on this machine? What changed between then and now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either you do not have php on your machine, your local server did not run correctly

Comment: Or PHP is not on the path, or is being searched for in the wrong location, or perhaps is only installed as a CGI or apache module and not CLI. Lots of possible reasons. Rather than a diagnostic answer like this, how about helping the OP to figure out where to look for more information?  If YOU were to come across this error (especially on a machine you've never used before), what steps would you take to figure out what's going on?

Comment: This is the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan make:migration create_tbl_payroll_leave_typev2_table
```

try dis command

Comment: if the user type an incorrect command in Laravel it would return a different error and not `bash: php: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

The command you entered was incorrect for creating migration. It must be like

```
php artisan make:migration your_migration_name
```